# Pandas groupby including value in all groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Is there any efficient way to groupby, but keeping a keyword value in all groups? For instance the word "all" belongs to every group instead of his own.

Such as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':         ['one',    'two',  'two',   'two',   'one'],
                   'condition1': ['all',    'red',  'all',   'green',   'red'],
                   'condition2': ['yellow', 'black','black', 'orange', 'all']})

df.groupby(['condition1','condition2']).apply(print)
```

So the row with ['all','black'] should be in the same group as ['red', 'black'], the expected output is :

```
    ID condition1 condition2
0  one        all     yellow
    ID condition1 condition2
2  two        all      black  # here is the point of the problem
1  two        red      black
4  one        red      black
    ID condition1 condition2
3  two      green        all
2  two        all      black  # this row belongs to this group too
```

I tried to substitute 'all' for the set of the column and explode it, it does work, but is not efficient in real life dataframes.

Edit: now I realize there are some pathological behaviours defining the groups when they have the word "all". So it may be impossible to solve this question, without constraining the scope or the allowed groups.

Comment: should all,black be in the same group as red,black and green,black? in that case, how is it possible? let's say group1 is (red,black); group2 is (green,black). how can (all,black) belong to both? it should belong to one group only.

Comment: @bpfrd, yes, good observation

Comment: @bpfrd, that is precisely the challenge of the question, some fields can be in multiple groups, if that is impossible using groupby, I'm open to other efficient solutions.

Comment: So the groups can overlap, that is not an issue, for instance if "all',"all" is provided his group should contain absolutely all the records in the df. Why so? because a group with more than one record is showing a duplicate, and I'm trying to find duplicates.

Comment: sorry but it's not still clear to me. if the 1st condition is all should it output the group of black or green or randomly from black and green?

Comment: @ZiurOlpa: After reading your comments, your desired output cannot be done with 1 line of `groupby` because there are many duplicates. The approach to your desired output is: (1) create a dummy column with your logic of how you want to group, then (2) using `concat` to get the new df you want